# Finishing YoutubeStandAlonePlayer after completing video in Android?

Tags: android, api, youtube, youtube-api

How to detect when the youtube video ends in YoutubeStandAlonePlayer using google api for Youtube player, I have to finish the player and write instructions after that once the video completes?

```
Intent intent = YouTubeStandalonePlayer.createVideoIntent(
          mActivity , DEVELOPER_KEY, VIDEO_ID, startTimeMillis, autoplay, lightboxMode);
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is currently not possible because **YouTubeStandalonePlayer** is the activity related to YouTube app which is another app where we doesn't have any control over other apps activity.

As said in documentation of YouTube Player Api,

> The second option is to use the YouTubeStandalonePlayer which will start video playback in a separate activity. This is simpler to use, however it gives you less flexibility and control over video playback. The StandalonePlayer supports two modes, either fullscreen or lightbox. In lightbox mode, the activity launching the player is still visible behind the player, slightly dimmed.

Link:- [docs](https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/reference/com/google/android/youtube/player/package-summary)